# Editable Java Syntax Highlighter for j2ee Application

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, syntaxhighlighter

I need a java **SyntaxHighlighter** for my jsp based web application.The field or TextArea should remain editable as I will need to save the file again as per the user changes of code.

I found this https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Overview though its highlighting  the code but the area is no more editable.

Answer (score 0):

Try [JSyntaxPane](https://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/). This will require using a JEditorPane instead of a JTextArea. For basic usage, look [here](https://code.google.com/p/jsyntaxpane/wiki/UsingNew).